# Split a row into multiple cells and keep the maximum value of second value for each gene

Tags: python, arrays, csv, optimization

I am new to Python and I prepared a script that will modify the following [csv file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2ynoLlCACXzSElFZ2poNllmVjg)

accordingly:

1) Each row that contains multiple Gene entries separated by the `///` such as:

```
C16orf52 /// LOC102725138 1.00551
```

should be transformed to:

```
C16orf52 1.00551  
LOC102725138 1.00551
```

2) The same gene may have different ratio values

```
AASDHPPT 0.860705  
AASDHPPT 0.983691
```

and we want to keep only the pair with the highest ratio value (delete the pair `AASDHPPT 0.860705`)

Here is the script I wrote but it does not assign the correct ratio values to the genes:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open('2column.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    a = list(reader)
gene = []
ratio = []
for t in range(len(a)):
    if '///' in a[t][0]:
        s = a[t][0].split('///')
        gene.append(s[0])
        gene.append(s[1])
        ratio.append(a[t][1])
        ratio.append(a[t][1])
    else:
        gene.append(a[t][0])
        ratio.append(a[t][1])
    gene[t] = gene[t].strip()

newgene = []
newratio = []
for i in range(len(gene)):
    g = gene[i]
    r = ratio[i]
    if g not in newgene:
        newgene.append(g)
    for j in range(i+1,len(gene)):
        if g==gene[j]:
            if ratio[j]>r:
                r = ratio[j]
    newratio.append(r)

for i in range(len(newgene)):
    print newgene[i] + '\t' + newratio[i]

if len(newgene) > len(set(newgene)):
    print 'missionfailed'
```

Thank you very much for any help or suggestion.

Comment: Hi Manolis, may be you should to learn about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think you ideally might want to store the gene in a dict, and when assigning the value, if the key exits, ignore if it's not larger than the current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('2column.csv') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

new_lines = {}
for line in lines:
    cols = line.split(',')
    for part in cols[0].split('///'):
        part = part.strip()
        if not part in new_lines:
            new_lines[part] = cols[1]
        else:
            if float(cols[1]) > float(new_lines[part]):
                new_lines[part] = cols[1]


import csv
with open('clean_2column.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for k, v in new_lines.items():
        writer.writerow([k, v])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. However, there was the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gsea.py", line 10, in <module>
    new_lines[part] = cols[1]
IndexError: list index out of range What do you suggest?

Comment: It's probably because you tested that on a different csv file than the one you shared. (check if you have the same separator `,`)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're importing Pandas, know that you have [I/O Tools](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/io.html) to read CSV files.

So first, let's import it that way :

```
df = pd.read_csv('2column.csv')
```

Then, you can extract the indexes where you have your '///' pattern:

```
l = list(df[df['Gene Symbol'].str.contains('///')].index)
```

Then, you can create your new rows :

```
for i in l :
    for sub in df['Gene Symbol'][i].split('///') : 
         df=df.append(pd.DataFrame([[sub, df['Ratio(ifna vs. ctrl)'][i]]], columns = df.columns))
```

Then, drop the old ones  :

```
df=df.drop(df.index[l])
```

Then, I'll do a little trick to remove your lowest duplicate values. First, I'll sort them by 'Ratio (ifna vs. ctrl)' then I'll [drop all the duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) but the first one :

```
df = df.sort('Ratio(ifna vs. ctrl)', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('Gene Symbol', keep='first')
```

If you want to keep your sorting by Gene Symbol and reset indexes to have simpler ones, simply do :

```
df = df.sort('Gene Symbol').reset_index(drop=True)
```

If you want to re-export your modified data to your csv, do :

```
df.to_csv('2column.csv')
```

---

EDIT : I edited my answer to correct syntax errors, I've tested this solution with your csv and it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

It uses the dictionary suggestion of Peter.

```
import csv

with open('2column.csv','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    original_file = list(reader)
    # gets rid of the header 
    original_file = original_file[1:]

# create an empty dictionary 
genes_ratio = {}

# loop over every row in the original file
for row in original_file:
    gene_name = row[0]
    gene_ratio = row[1]
    # check if /// is in the string if so split the string
    if '///' in gene_name:
        gene_names = gene_name.split('///')
        # loop over all the resulting compontents
        for gene in gene_names:
            # check if the component is in the dictionary 
            # if not in dictionary set value to gene_ratio
            if gene not in genes_ratio:
                genes_ratio[gene] = gene_ratio
            # if in dictionary compare value in dictionary to gene_ratio
            # if dictionary value is smaller overwrite value
            elif genes_ratio[gene] < gene_ratio:
                genes_ratio[gene] = gene_ratio
    else:
        if gene_name not in genes_ratio:
            genes_ratio[gene_name] = gene_ratio
        elif genes_ratio[gene_name] < gene_ratio:
            genes_ratio[gene_name] = gene_ratio

#loop over dictionary and print gene names and their ratio values 
for key in genes_ratio:
    print key, genes_ratio[key]
```